# ajax loading image

Tags: ajax

I have a page which checks a form for validation, the main checks are for if the email or username is already in the database. I have this working fine, but I cannot figure out how to add a loading image...for when the user changes either username or email when it is being checked.

Yy function to check username is below, its similar for the checking email

```
function check_username(username)
{
var httpRequest;
make_request()
function stateck() 
    {

    if(httpxml.readyState==4)

        { 
        if (httpxml.responseText.indexOf ("Username Ok") >= 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("username").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            document.getElementById("username").style.color = "white";
            document.getElementById("username_div").style.display = 'none';
            usernameok = true;

        }

         else 
        {
            document.getElementById("username").style.backgroundColor = "red";
            document.getElementById("username_div").style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById("username_div").innerHTML=httpxml.responseText;
            usernameok = false;

        }
        checkCanSubmit();           
        }


    }

httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
user_url="check_username.php?username=" + username.value;
httpxml.open("GET",user_url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
}
```

I have already tried jQuery library, and I prefer it this way.

Answer (score 1):

ajaxload.info does indeed work well, but you don't need to bother with a div and background-image. Simply create an `<img>`, using document.createElement, then set the src of the image, then add it to your document:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = '&lt;the URL of your loading image>';
function stateck() {
    ...
```

Now you can insert the newly created `img` into your document, then remove it in stateck().

Comment: Good point about the background image. Personally, I prefer to do it that way because it feels more webapp-y (for instance, you can't click, right-click, or click-and-drag the gif). It's nothing more than a preference.

Comment: ok thanks, how would I remove the image? is there a hide function etc

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't thought of that. Previously, I'd used this trick inside a <button>, so that wasn't an issue. Theoretically the best way to use it would be a background-image on an existing element, but that might not be possible in Elliott's case.

Comment: Elliot: If you'd added it to, say the "username" div, you would do the following:

    document.getElementById("username").removeChild(img);

P.S. You might want to look into jQuery (http://jquery.com/); it makes common stuff like DOM manipulation and AJAX much easier.